# how to do 2D animations in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, animation

How can you move 2D objects around in OpenGL? What is the mechanism? E.g., do we need to control frames?

An example code snippet would be welcome!

Comment: depends what kind of animation you need - I would consider simple moving-objects-around-like animation as a vector of transfomations, where each element stores transformation for corresponding frame, and all you need is to multiply it by proper ProjectionModelviewMatrix. If you wanted to achieve more fancy effect than simple moving object, you could always change its texture each frame of animation: all you need is to deal with things called sprite sheets and instead of changing transformation change texture coordinates per vertex.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The short answer is that you can move an object by modifying the modelview matrix.  This can be done in several ways and it depends on your coding preferences and which version of opengl drivers you have available.

Here's some partial code to get you started in the right direction:

The following is deprecated in Opengl 3.0+ (but even then it is still available via the compatibility profile).

```
// you'll need a game loop to make some opengl calls each frame
while(!done)
{
    // clear color buffers, depth buffers, etc
    initOpenglFrame();

    glPushMatrixf();
        glTranslatef(obj->getX(), obj->getY(), obj->getZ());
        obj->draw();
    glPopMatrixf();

    // move the object 0.01 units to the left each tick
    obj->setX(obj->getX() + 0.01);

    // flush, swap buffers, etc
    finishOpenglFrame();
}
```

For OpenGL 3.0 and beyond, glPushMatrixf(), glPopMatrixf(), glTranslatef(), and similar fixed function pipeline interface is all deprecated.  If you need to using OpenGL 3.0 or greater, you'll want to do the same type of solution but you'll need your own implementation of matricies and a matrix stack.  I think that discussion is beyond the scope of your question.

For further reading, and to get started with OpenGL, I'd recommend you check out nehe.gamedev.net.  If you would like to get started with OpenGL 3.X, then I'd recommend purchasing the Opengl Superbible 5th Edition.  Great book!